# Receive and send bluetooth audio to bluetooth device from Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, audio, bluetooth

I have the Raspberry Pi 3 with the latest version of Raspbian Buster and I am looking for a way to have the RPi to receive Bluetooth Audio from a phone or laptop and output the audio to a bluetooth device (speaker, headphones, etc.). From my understanding, the RPi may require an external bluetooth dongle, one to receive the Bluetooth Audio while the internal bluetooth module sends the audio to the bluetooth device. Am I getting ahead of myself on something not feasible with the Raspberry Pi?